# Como determinar o valor de X usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como eu posso descobrir o valor de X levando em conta que a formula base é essa? E usando apenas JavaScript?

```
1056261433 * X² + 431977909 * X - 2.022 = 281860832
```

Existem funções que façam isso ou precisarei criar, poderiam me orientar por favor? A intenção é criar uma função em JS que dê o valor de X .

Comment: Isso é uma pergunta sobre como resolver operação matemática e não exatamente um recurso de linguagem. Javascript pode como praticamente qualquer outra linguagem determinar o "X" (variável) de um calculo aritmético, se você criar (ou usar uma existente) função pra isso.

Comment: Relacionado: ["Resolução de equações"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43857/215)

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver uma [equação de segundo grau](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_quadr%C3%A1tica) como essa ai você pode usar a [fórmula de Baskara](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_quadr%C3%A1tica#F.C3.B3rmula).

Se os fatores que multiplicam o X e o X<sup>2</sup> forem sempre esses da pergunta, não precisa usar Javascript. Você pode fazer a conta na calculadora e obter as duas raizes desejadas na mão. Dá `X=-0.760057` ou `X=0.351089`, [segundo o wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=++1056261433+*+X%C2%B2+%2B+431977909+*+X+-+2.022+%3D+281860832)

Se os parâmetros da equação puderem mudar então você pode programar a fórmula usando Javascript. A única função especial que você iria precisar é a `Math.sqrt` pra tirar a raiz quadrada.

Comment: Procurei pela net funçoes para realizar isto porém as que achei nao levam em conta o `= 281860832` vc tem algo?

Comment: Se você subtrair 281860832 dos dois lados da equação você fica com `1056261433 * X² + 431977909 * X - 281860834.022 = 0`. Talvez seja uma boa ideia treinar um pouco a sua álgebra :)

Answer (score 1):

Como já [disse o hugomg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58913), trata-se de uma equação de segundo grau, e todas elas têm a seguinte forma:

> ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c = 0

No seu caso:

> a = 1056261433
>   b = 431977909
>   c = -281860832 - 2.022 = -281860834.022

Essas equações podem ser resolvidas pela fórmula de Bhaskara:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>[Imagem da fórmula: Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_quadr%C3%A1tica#F.C3.B3rmula)</sub>

Em JavaScript, uma implementação simples toma os valores de `a`, `b` e `c` e retorna os dois resultados possíveis:

```js
var a = 1056261433; 
var b = 431977909;
var c = -281860834.022;

function bhaskara(a, b, c) {
  
   var ret = [];
   var d = delta(a, b, c);
   ret[0] = ((b * -1) - Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
   ret[1] = ((b * -1) + Math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
   return ret;
  
   // calcula o delta separadamente
   function delta(a, b, c) {
       return Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c); 
   }
  
}

document.body.innerHTML = bhaskara(a, b, c).join(', ');
```

A limitação desse código é que ele não lida com [números complexos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_complexo), caso o delta da equação seja negativo. Se precisar lidar com esse tipo de valor, precisaria criar uma representação dos complexos como arrays ou objetos, ou usar uma biblioteca como a [math.js](http://mathjs.org/).