# Quebrar uma string contendo um polinômio

Tags: java, string

Criei uma classe com duas propriedades como no exemplo abaixo:

```
class Polinomio {
    private int coeficientes;
    private int expoente;
}
```

Vou criar uma lista para receber um tipo polinômio aonde vou receber 
os termos para realizar as operações soma, subtração e multiplicação.

```
List<Polinomio> lst = new ArrayList<Polinomio>();
```

Quando eu passar uma *string* como qualquer uma dessas abaixo no construtor gostaria de quebrar os termos, mas não estou conseguindo.

- a) -4x^5 + 3x^2 + 4
- b) -4x^3 + 3x^2 - 8
- c) 3x^3 - 3x^2 + 4
- d) 3x^3 - 3x^2 + 2

Quando quebrar ficaria.

- a) lst = p1(-4,5),p2(3,2),p3(4,0)
- b) lst = p1(-4,3),p2(3,2),p3(-8,0)
- c) lst = p1(3,3),p2(-3,2),p3(4,0)
- d) lst = p1(3,3),p2(-3,2),p4(4,0)

p1,p2,p3.. são as posições que os elementos vão estar na lista.
No caso do último termo quando for só 1 número sem "x" ele grava como zero. Por padrão os polinômios vão ter essa mesma variável "x".

Como posso quebrar os termos?

Comment: Relacionado: ["Resolução de equações"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43857/215) (um pouquinho mais geral, talvez *overkill* pro seu caso, mas estou mencionando caso ache útil)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html): alguma coisa do tipo `Pattern.compile("(?=[+-])").split(…)` vai retornar uma lista de monômios (pedacinhos tipo `-2x^3`, `+3x^4`, `7`); você pode usar ideias parecidas (quebrar no `^` e no `x`) pra separar coeficientes e expoentes.

Você tem que se atentar ao fato de que, normalmente, não se escrevem muitos termos de um polinômio (e.g. `-x^3+x^2`, onde os coeficientes são todos implícitos), e você pode encontrar um monômio “fantasma” no começo da lista que o `Pattern` vai retornar, quando o polinômio começar com um sinal de menos.

(Na página do `Pattern` tem uma explicação de como funcionam expressões regulares — o parâmetro do `.compile()` — mas o que você precisa saber pra entender como essa ideia funciona é que e.g. `Pattern.compile("(?=[aeiou])").split("abacaxi")` vai retornar a lista `{"ab", "ac", "ax", "i"}` — de uma forma geral, o parâmetro do `.split()` vai ser quebrado imediatamente antes dos caracteres que você colocou entre colchetes no `.compile()`.)

Comment: Uma regex pra pegar um monômio: `(-?\d*x\^\d+|-?\d*x|-?\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

Deu Certo!
código que fiz de exemplo agora consigo ir caminhando daqui, obrigado!

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String poli = "-3x^3 - 3x^2 + 4";
    Pattern.compile("(?=[+-])").split(poli);

    Pattern pegapoli = Pattern.compile("(?=[+-])");    
    String[] m = pegapoli.split(poli);

    System.out.println(m[0]);
    System.out.println(m[1]);
    System.out.println(m[2]);

}
```